# IPython and OS X terminal output is line wrapping before column limit

Tags: python, terminal, pandas, ipython, osx-mavericks

I'm using IPython working with the pandas module which allows for the `DataFrame` object. When I'm running some code, I get an output where the `DataFrame` output is wrapping before the width of my terminal despite that the terminal width should accommodate the length. This issue seems to be isolated only to the pandas Series and DataFrame objects and not say, a long list.

Running `pip uninstall readline` and then reinstalling readline through easy_install and restarting IPython did not solve the problem.

It would be helpful to see my data not broken up like that, but I honestly don't know where to begin to fix this. Any insight?

[image: offending output]

Comment: What happens if you resize the terminal *before starting* IPython? If the problem shows up only on `DataFrame` it means that it's the `DataFrame`'s formatter fault. It may be that, for some reason, ipython isn't able to receive width changes or that the formatter doesn't correctly handle different sizes.

Comment: If the problem is getting terminal size changes from Terminal.app through the multiple layers to your code, you can go even farther and just create a new Terminal profile with a starting size of 256 or whatever instead of 80 (in Preferences | Settings | Window).

Comment: @Bakuriu that sounds about right. There's some formatting on `DataFrame` that is wrapping the lines, regardless of the terminal width which seems to be correctly accessed despite multiple layers (e.g. that long list outputs to full width). I actually found a workaround so I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a workaround that allows the console output to be more readable. Calling `to_string()` on the `DataFrame` object returns a string representation of the object, skirting around whatever inherent formatting that `DataFrame` contains, especially since the goal is readability.

```
data = DataFrame(some_long_list)
print data.to_string() # outputs to console's full-width
```

EDIT:
From pandas docs: "New since 0.10.0, wide DataFrames will now be printed across multiple rows by default". I'm seeing that this helps as a default so that instead of cramming rows onto the next line, you'll see separation by column. There are two additional methods to configure output width:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('line_width', 40) # default is 80
```

or to turn off the wrap feature completely:

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```